# Open up .MHT link in excel

Tags: html, excel, mhtml

So I have a local sever website that we have a status board at my command center (military). We are displaying an excel spreadsheet on this website as a .mht

I want to create a button to edit this (because the people I work with cannot figure out how to right click open with excel)

Basically what I would love to see is a button called edit that would launch excel and open the .mht file in excel.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

As .mht is only supported by Internet Explorer I guess your users are using Internet Explorer.

For security reasons it is not easily possible to run code on local computer pushed to the client from webserver - without the user seeing questions like where do you want to save the file, do you trust the file etc etc.

I would search for answer in following directions:

**1** Internet Explorer can run nearly any code with the HTML user interface through the [.hta file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application) - may be outdated today

**2** Editing spreadsheet documents directly from the browser is nicely supported if you host the Excel files on [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/)

**3** Similar easy to use online spreadsheet editing should be possible through Microsoft's services `OneDrive` and `Office Online`